# Handle Future with transform

Tags: scala, exception, bots, future

I have a telegram bot on Scala and I want to send the image to the user if it exists and the message "Sorry, the image doesn't exist" if it's not. And I have a function `getImage(tag)`, which returns `Future.successful(link)` or `Future.failed(NoImageException(msg))`.

```
onCommand("/img") { implicit msg =>
  val tag = msg.text.get.drop("/img ".length)
  try {
    if (tag.isEmpty) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException()
    service.getImage(tag).transform {
      case Success(link) => Success(
        try {
          replyWithPhoto(InputFile(link))
        } catch {
          case _ => reply(link) // maybe it isn't a photo...
        })
      case Failure(e) => Success(reply(e.getMessage))
    }.void
  } catch {
    case _: IndexOutOfBoundsException => reply("Empty argument list. Usage: /img tag").void
  }}
```

And this code sends an image if it's a success, but it doesn't send a message if it's a failure (but it definitely chooses `case Failure(e)` in this case)

Comment: I think you need to use onComplete instead of transform

Comment: @VladislavKievski but in this case it'll return Unit instead of Future[Unit] and I don't know how to rewrite it idiomatically :(

Comment: @RonaldSMerritt what does `reply` function return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reply` family of functions return a `Future[Message]`. Currently you wrap the result of `reply` in `Success`, so the result of your `transform` is `Future[Future[Message]]`, which doesn't work. Instead you can use `transformWith`, which expects a `Future` result from its argument:

```
onCommand("/img") { implicit msg =>
  val tag = msg.text.get.drop("/img ".length)
  val message: Future[Message] =
    if (tag.isEmpty) reply("Empty argument list. Usage: /img tag")
    else {
      service.getImage(tag).transformWith {
        case Success(link) => replyWithPhoto(InputFile(link)).recoverWith {
          case _ => reply(link) // maybe it isn't a photo...
        }
        case Failure(e) => reply(e.getMessage)
      }
    }
  message.void
}
```

Note, that I have also removed both `try` operators. The external is just unnecessary, because you can just use `if`/`else`. The internal won't work at all, because `replyWithPhoto` returns a `Future`. So it doesn't throw errors, and you need to `recover` or `transform` when it fails.